# How can I test a web site on multiple versions of Firefox?

Tags: firefox

I'm looking for a way to test websites on multiple versions of Firefox. I reckon at a time only one version of Firefox can be setup on each computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use MultiFox. I have posted a link below.

http://www.webmonkey.com/blog/Test_Multiple_Firefox_Versions_with_MultiFirefox

I think that this is a good choice because it can run the different versions of FireFox, but also because it can run them at the same time.

Edit: the new address is http://davemartorana.com/multifirefox

Comment: Mac        only

Comment: Here's the final destination: http://davemartorana.com/multifirefox/ - thanks, checking this out.

Answer (score 4):

I use [Browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) for this. Nothing to install.

You can also use the [portable versions](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) of Firefox, and [edit your FirefoxPortable.ini file](http://sazwqa.wordpress.com/2008/08/06/running-multiple-versions-of-firefox-on-windows/) if you wish to run them simulataneously.

Comment: Wouldn't that be cumbersome? Anything that allows running it locally on the dev machine?

Comment: updated to reflect

Comment: +1 for browsershots. It's much easier than installing tonnes of browsers. And once its all done you can download all the screenshots in a zip file.

Comment: I must agree, Browsershots is the way to go.  Don't commit yourself to one browser, either.

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple versions of firefox simultaneously on the same machine, by using a seperate profile for each one. This [blog post](http://blog.codefront.net/2007/08/20/how-to-have-firefox-3-and-firefox-2-running-at-the-same-time/) goes through how to set it up. (It talks about FF2 & 3, but the same should also work for FF3.5)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do personally for testing... run [portable firefox](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable#legacy) (from [portable apps](http://portableapps.com)) with different versions. Of course the latest 3.5 is native install on my computer, but FF3, FF 2, and FF 1 - I run as portable apps.

[image]

they can all run simultaneously too by the way.

[Portable Firefox Legacy Versions](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable#legacy)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I always prefer to use Utilu Mozilla Firefox Collection 
http://utilu.com/UtiluMFC/

Comment: Please be a little bit more detailed if you recommend software to other users: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers